# regex should match only one of two types of quoted strings

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes, single-quotes

I need a regex that match a string that is surrounded by double quotes. It should not match a string surrounded by double quotes if this pattern is surrounded by single quotes:

```
"string"
" 'xyz' "
"  `"    "
"  `" `"   "
"  `" `" `"  "
'  ' "should match" '  '
'   "should not match"   '
```

Now I have (https://regex101.com/r/z5PayV/1)

```
(?:"(([^"]*`")*[^"]*|[^"]*)")
```

that matches all lines. But the last line should not be matched. Any solution?

Comment: Don't the last 2 lines fit the same situation as far as this is concerned: A string surrounded by double quotes, also surrounded by single quotes? Why should the second to last match, but not the very last?

Comment: What do you mean with `this pattern `? Your whole current regex?

Comment: @dvo The last 2 lines do not fit the same situation. If one think of shell scripts like bash or powershell the last line represents one string while the seconds last line represents 3 strings. The answer shows that regex are able to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go past single quotes to exclude them from the match

***update***

For C# it has to be done like this.
Just uses a simple CaptureCollection to get all
the quoted matches.

```
(?:'[^']*'|(?:"(([^"]*`")*[^"]*|[^"]*)")|[\S\s])+
```

Expanded

```
 (?:
      ' [^']* '

   |  
      (?:
           "
           (                             # (1 start)
                ( [^"]* `" )*                 # (2)
                [^"]* 
             |  [^"]* 
           )                             # (1 end)
           "
      )
   |  
      [\S\s] 
 )+
```

C# code

```
var str =
"The two sentences are 'He said \"Hello there\"' and \"She said 'goodbye' and 'another sentence'\"\n" +
"\"  `\"    \"\n" +
"\"  `\"    \"\n" +
"\"  `\" `\"   \"\n" +
"\"  `\" `\" `\"  \"\n" +
"'   \"   \"   '\n" +
"\"string\"\n" +
"\" 'xyz' \"\n" +
"\"  `\"    \"\n" +
"\"  `\" `\"   \"\n" +
"\"  `\" `\" `\"  \"\n" +
"'  ' \"should match\" '  '\n" +
"'   \"should not match\"   '\n";

var rx = new Regex( "(?:'[^']*'|(?:\"(([^\"]*`\")*[^\"]*|[^\"]*)\")|[\\S\\s])+" );

Match M = rx.Match( str );
if (M.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection cc = M.Groups[1].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", cc[i].Value);
}
```

Output

```
She said 'goodbye' and 'another sentence'
  `"
  `"
  `" `"
  `" `" `"
string
 'xyz'
  `"
  `" `"
  `" `" `"
should match
```

---

***Excuse this, it is the way it's done in PCRE engine***

```
'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:"(([^"]*`")*[^"]*|[^"]*)")`
```

https://regex101.com/r/gMiVDU/1

```
   ' [^']* '
   (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
|  
   (?:
        "
        (                             # (1 start)
             ( [^"]* `" )*                 # (2)
             [^"]* 
          |  [^"]* 
        )                             # (1 end)
        "
   )
```

___________________________-

Comment: I accepted this answer, although the second noncapturing group is wrong I think. If I remove it, the double quotes were matched too. @sln could you confirm this? Thank you.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam - Can you be specific which regex and where you think there is a problem ? Thank you.

Comment: @@TobiasWollgam - Note that on the C# regex, the entire string is always matched in a single match. That is by design, it doesn't hurt anything, nor slow it down. All of the group 1 captures are recorded in a list. This is like a findall() type function on steroids.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear.  In your output I miss the leading and trailing double quotes. So my solution was to remove the second noncapturing group `?:` that the regex become `(?:'[^']*'|("(([^"]*´")*[^"]*|[^"]*)")|[\S\s])+` (replaced the original backtick by foretick, because the backticks are used for code marking in comments). Now the output of your c# code contains the double quotes. As I didn't test it with my production code, where one give a Regex-object to the c# matching code that comes from third party, I do not know if one of the regexs work.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam - I see. Sure, you can use capture groups around the quotes as well if you want to see them. In fact, all the groups maintain a separate capture collection (list) you can iterate through after the match. Example:   `CaptureCollection cc1 = M.Groups[1].Captures; CaptureCollection cc2 = M.Groups[2].Captures; CaptureCollection cc3 = M.Groups[3].Captures;` etc...

Answer (score 0):

The answer looks quite complex, how is this one:

^"(\d+|\D+)"$

is it too simple?

The idea here is to check the string starts and ends with the double quote ("), anything within the double quote including the single quote is allowed.

Comment: Please elaborate as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you check your solution against the examples supplied?